# AngularJS directive change model value not associated with directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive for validating creditcard luhn, and length.  As a validator of the number it works great.  The algorithm used is based off of a jquery plugin (sans jquery) that also returns the card type to me.  The ending result is something like

```
{
    luhn_valid: true,
    length_valid: true
    card_type: {
        name: 'visa'
    }
}
```

So it gives me the card type name.  I want to assign this to a different model variable so that I can pass both the card type and card number to REST api to add the card.  The problem is I do not know how to access a model that is not declared associated with the directive.

```
<input type="text" name="cardNumber" ng-model="cardCtrl.form.inputs.cardNumber" 
    credit-card-validator card-type-model="cardCtrl.form.inputs.cardType">
```

In the example above I add an extra attribute to pass the model name to the directive.  I have passed $scope to the directive and can see cardCtrl as a child of $scope, so I feel I should be able to get to the model from it, but I am not sure the best way to do it.

Thoughts on the best way to get access to this other model?

Comment: Can you please add a jsFiddle/plnkr for your code?

Comment: how is this `card-type-model` declared in your directive code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the directive controller, by calling `$scope.$parent.'ParentControllerVariableName'`, you can get the value of the controller scope variable from the directive, but this is not a good practice.

You can create a factory and set your value in factory method and define a get method. Inject this factory into your directive and get the value from your factory.

Comment: Thank you this was so simple and exactly what I needed.